# Is this correct between sets and intervals?

Tags: analysis

Does the union of intervals form a set? I mean the union of $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ is a set and if yes, then how?

Comment: Yes, it is a set.

Answer (score 1):

A set is a collection of elements. In this case, all elements are real numbers.

Any interval $(a,b)$ *is a set* (the set of those real numbers $x$ which satisfy $a<x<b$.)

The union of any two sets is still a collection of elements, i.e. **is a set**.

Answer (score 1):

A set is just a collection of elements, therefore, you have a set, since you have a collection of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As "explicit" sets these intervals are written:
$$(0,1)=\{x:0<x<1,\space x \in \mathbb{R}\}, (1,2)=\{x:1<x<2,\space x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
So the union is:
$$(0,1) \cup (1,2)=\{x:0<x<2,\space x\neq 1,\space x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is because each  interval is set and union of two sets is set.